# Replace text in a Google Sheets Query Formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a a query formula
Example: Query(A:AF, "Select A, B")

One of the column values returns Q1, Q2, Q3, or Q4 based on the quarter value.
I am looking to pull only the 1, 2, 3, or 4 value.

Is there any way to do this within the "Select A, B" Statement alone?

I cannot change the DataSource (A:AF) part as it is running from AppScript with multiple data range matches.

Comment: Why would you QUERY range `A:AF` if you only need data from the first two columns of that as the return? I sense that your example isn't close to your actual `QUERY` formula. It would help in this case if you share the *full* formula, so that the volunteer contributors here have the entire context. (If it really is as simple as two columns, there is a simple solution; but if you actually want 15 columns returned, the solution would change drastically.) Please also include the data types involved for each return column (i.e., numeric, string, Boolean).

Comment: Hey @ErikTyler!
Apologies that the question was not clear enough. 

I am NOT looking to break down a column data TYPE or interpret the data range. 
My question was is there a way to convert values in a column "Quarter" from "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4" to 1, 2, 3, 4

This is an EXAMPLE of the query
=QUERY('All Data'!A:AF,"SELECT A, M, SUM(S), SUM(T), SUM(T)/SUM(S) WHERE A IS NOT NULL GROUP BY A, M,-1)

A -> (STRING) UserName
M -> (STRING) Quarter

Mentioning it again to aid with understanding, I want M which currently has values as "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4" to be represented as 1, 2, 3, 4

Comment: You seem to still be emphasizing that even the formula above is an EXAMPLE and not the actual formula. Please clarify. If you are asking whether you can use the QUERY "Select" clause to accomplish your goal, no, you can't. But there are ways to pre-process data fed to the QUERY to accomplish this. I would just need to know ***the exact*** formula.

Comment: =ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({'Q3''16 Data'!A4:O,N('Q3''16 Data'!P4:AF)},"SELECT Col"&MATCH("Quarter",'Q3''16 Data'!A3:AF3,0)&", Col"&MATCH("Year",'Q3''16 Data'!A3:AF3,0)&", Col"&MATCH("Adv Plan",'Q3''16 Data'!A3:AF3,0)&", Col"&MATCH("Channel",'Q3''16 Data'!A3:AF3,0)&", Col"&MATCH("Sub-Channel",'Q3''16 Data'!A3:AF3,0)&", Col"&MATCH("Team",'Q3''16 Data'!A3:AF3,0)&", Col"&MATCH("Pod",'Q3''16 Data'!A3:AF3,0)&", SUM(Col"&MATCH("Rev A Quota $",'Q3''16 Data'!A3:AF3,0)&"), SUM(Col"&MATCH("Rev A Attainment $",'Q3''16 Data'!A3:AF3,0)&"), SUM(Col"&MATCH("Rev B Quota $",'Q3''16 Data'!A3:AF3,0)&"),

Comment: SUM(Col"&MATCH("Rev B Attainment $",'Q3''16 Data'!A3:AF3,0)&") WHERE Col"&MATCH("Quarter",'Q3''16 Data'!A3:AF3,0)&" IS NOT NULL GROUP BY Col"&MATCH("Quarter",'Q3''16 Data'!A3:AF3,0)&", Col"&MATCH("Year",'Q3''16 Data'!A3:AF3,0)&", Col"&MATCH("Adv Plan",'Q3''16 Data'!A3:AF3,0)&", Col"&MATCH("Channel",'Q3''16 Data'!A3:AF3,0)&", Col"&MATCH("Sub-Channel",'Q3''16 Data'!A3:AF3,0)&", Col"&MATCH("Team",'Q3''16 Data'!A3:AF3,0)&", Col"&MATCH("Pod",'Q3''16 Data'!A3:AF3,0)&"

Comment: label SUM(Col"&MATCH("Rev A Quota $",'Q3''16 Data'!A3:AF3,0)&") 'Rev_A_Quota$', SUM(Col"&MATCH("Rev A Attainment $",'Q3''16 Data'!A3:AF3,0)&") 'Rev_A_Attainment$', SUM(Col"&MATCH("Rev B Quota $",'Q3''16 Data'!A3:AF3,0)&") 'Rev_B_Quota$', SUM(Col"&MATCH("Rev B Attainment $",'Q3''16 Data'!A3:AF3,0)&") 'Rev_B_Attainment$'",-1))

Comment: This is the exact formula I am using
@ErikTyler

Comment: As I suspected, the formula is much longer than the post or early comment indicate (which really renders the post moot). Going through a formula of that length would require access to the actual sheet. It would also constitute custom, time-intensive, expert-level work, which goes beyond the scope of this free, volunteer-run forum. However, what I can tell you at a glance is that it appears you are *only* asking for Q3 data with this QUERY. So why not just use a constant in the "Select" clause in place of the actual "Quarter" data?

Comment: To implement the above, you can try replacing this `SELECT Col"&MATCH("Quarter",'Q3''16 Data'!A3:AF3,0)&` with this `SELECT 3 "&`. Then add this at the very end of the "Select" clause (before the closing quotation mark): `LABEL 3 '' `

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a way to do this inside the query. Formatting options and data manipulation functions are mainly for [numbers and dates](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#data-manipulation-functions).

But, if there's any type of date column corresponding to your Q1-Q4 value, you could query that column with a `quarter()` scalar function, like:

```
SELECT A, quarter(B)
```